# Fetch API SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 169681

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fetch

Im trying to make an HTTP request using fetch, but it's blowing up with the error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 169681". This is my request function:

```
async getOportunidades() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://gcsupport.internal.vodafone.com/bpa/webservices/GCCRM.asmx/GetCardsLeadsList',
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({userId: 29188,tipoAplic:'T'})
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        this.listaOportunidades = data;
        return data
    } catch(e) {
         console.log(e);
    }   
}
```

Looking at the response at Chrome developer tools all seems fine:
[image]

and after inspecting it seems I am receiving my json data as expected, and the json string is well formed, but for some reason it "breaks" on position 169681.
[image]

Is there like a size limit on the response?!

Just for the sake of my sanity I tried to make the same request using Jquery AJAX and everything runs fine!! Thing is, I don't want to use Jquery on my project. Anyone more experienced with Fetch has any idea why this is happening?

*********MY AJAX CALL********

```
$.ajax({
url:'https://gcsupport.internal.vodafone.com/bpa/webservices/GCCRM.asmx/GetCardsLeadsList',
type: 'POST',
data: {userId: 29188, tipoAplic: 'T'},
success: function(data) {
console.log(data)
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
console.log(xhr, status, error)
}
})
```

******webservice code*******
[image]

Sorry if this is a duplicate question but all the issues I could find were related to "Unexpected token < at position 0" which is not my case.

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: check are u using `jsonp` ??

Comment: or console.log(res.text())

Comment: console.log(res.text()[169681]) or console.log(res.text().slice(169670)) to see context

Comment: it seems there is a weird object outside of the json array {"d":null} that is causing the parsing issue. I have no idea where this is coming from, because invoking my webservice directly doesnt return this object at the end

Comment: well, if the jquery request works, you could compare the two results and see what's different.  save out the raw responses and diff them.  and the requests too.  be sure to add in the headers

Comment: Well the difference it's in this weird {"d": null} object outside of the json array. For some reason the AJAX request is not putting it. I have no idea where this is coming from

Comment: sounds like a bug in the web service. the web service isn't returning early after it finishes writing the json data and is writing more results in a later segment of code.  something in the requests is probably different.  show your $.ajax code

Comment: I edited my question with my AJAX request. Everything works fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service is not handling JSON requests correctly.  I've created a fetch example below that uses form data that should work.  $.ajax interprets the object given as form data which is why it works.

What's happening is that your web service outputs *BOTH* data generated from JSON body and form data.  It needs to be fixed to immediately return after handling JSON body, and not continuing to try to interpret form data (which in the case of a JSON body is blank).

tl;dr Web service is bugged.  Does not end writing response after using JSON body data to generate response.  So, after `.write(responseFromJSONData())` it doesn't return and break, and tries to continue to `.write(responseFromFormData([blankFormData]))`, resulting in two JSON objects being attached to your response.

```
async getOportunidades() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://gcsupport.internal.vodafone.com/bpa/webservices/GCCRM.asmx/GetCardsLeadsList',
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({userId: 29188,tipoAplic:'T'})
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        this.listaOportunidades = data;
        return data
    } catch(e) {
         console.log(e);
    }   
}
```

Comment: The issue remains it seems. I edited tbe question with the webservice code. Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: in the response of your $.ajax code, did you check that the console.log(data), specifically the contents of data, is actually parsed JSON and not just a string with the same malformed {"d": null} attached to the end?  change it to console.log(data, typeof data) to make sure data isn't a string.  also you should be able to just return an object from the web service method, and it should handle the serialization for you.

Comment: the content of AJAX console.log(data) is an object with my json data well formed

Comment: Try the new fetch I've posted here with the `Accept: */*` header tacked on.  It's possible that the web service is doing the response.writes, and then using the void return value (which is null) and adding an extra serialized JSON object {d:null}.  And for some reason `*/*` type disables the automatic JSON generation.  If you are generating the JSON string yourself and the headers, you should probably turn off the ResponseFormat Json and just add the JSON type header yourself

Comment: It's throwing me a "System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

Comment: that's really strange.  it should be x-www-formurlencoded since its form data.

Comment: and now that I'm looking at it, your chrome dev tools request headers are strange.  user-agent isn't in there.  try this fetch above?  can you get a snapshot of your chrome dev tools report on the request header for the $.ajax request?

Comment: I've added the snapshot to my question

Comment: you posted the same image for both request header snapshots.  was that intentional?  I don't really see anything of interest, except that you should perhaps instead of having a void return value, return a list of whatever getcardsleadslist returns instead of generating the json string yourself.  (which is okay and should work, but it makes more sense to let the asp.net framework do it for you. it looks like to me that it is still for some odd reason returning both .write data and the framework's generated json data).   the text/plain error seems like something is intercepting your request

Comment: Sorry that was not intentional. After all It seems that removing the responseFormat line in the webservice, and changing the fetch body to URLSearchParams and Content-Type did the trick :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = JSON.stringify({"userId":29188,"tipoAplic":"T"});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://gcsupport.internal.vodafone.com/bpa/webservices/GCCRM.asmx/GetCardsLeadsList");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.send(data);
```

> Try this one.